# MKPointAnnotation - Default show title and animated?

Tags: ios, ios5, mapkit

In my viewWillAppear for a view I have

```
MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];

[point setCoordinate:(myLocation)];
[point setTitle:@"Here it is!"];

[mapView addAnnotation:point];

[mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
```

This adds the point to the map as I intend.  However I have to tap it in order to see the callout.

How can I have it show the callout by default?

I tried adding this right after:
    `[self.mapView selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES];`

But it didn't seem to work... do I have to use a real annotation and not a MKPointAnnotation to do this?

Comment: An MKPointAnnotation is a real annotation--that's not the problem.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884379/mkannotation-not-getting-selected-in-ios5, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978897/how-to-trigger-mkannotationviews-callout-view-without-touching-the-pin, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You named your annotation `point` not `annotation`:

```
 [mapView selectAnnotation:point animated:YES];
```

It happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 0):

swift 3

reminder this action after the addAnnotation.

```
mapView.addAnnotation(point)

mapView.selectAnnotation(point, animated: true)
```